# Erros de Session Hibernate - getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Por favor, gostaria que, se possível, opinassem sobre esse código.
Se esta coerente ou se precisa ser melhorado pois constantemente tenho erros de `org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed` ou

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:202).
```

Segue códigos:

```
    private Session session = null;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    public UsuarioDAO() {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getFactory();
    }

    public Usuarios autenticarUsuario(Usuarios usu) {
        Usuarios usuario = Singleton.getUsuarios();
        String hql = "FROM Usuarios WHERE emausu = :emausu AND senusu = :senusu";

        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            usuario = (Usuarios) session.createQuery(hql)
                    .setParameter("emausu", usu.getEmausu())
                    .setParameter("senusu", usu.getSenusu())
                    .uniqueResult();

            if (!session.getTransaction().wasCommitted()) {
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            if (session.getTransaction() != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            throw erro;
        }
        return usuario;
    }
```

Abaixo segue meu hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--  Configurações de Conexão ao Banco de Dados  -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meuBanco?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">minhaSenha</property>


        <!--  **** Propriedades do C3P0 - Pool de Conexão ***  -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>


        <!--  ****SQL Dialect ****  -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


        <!--  ****Gerenciamento do Contexto da Sessão****  -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <!--  ****Desabilitando Cache de segundo nível****  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>


        <!--  Mapeamento das Entidades  -->
        Minhas entidades

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Segue HibernateUtil.java:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null){
             sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            SessionFactory session = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return session;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Criação da SessionFactory failed." + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Além dos erros listados acima, também tenho erros de `max_user_connections`.

O método mostrado acima é somente um de vários métodos, nesta mesma formatação, em minha aplicação.
Portanto, a melhoria que for feita aqui, será duplicada para toda a aplicação.

Estou exaustivamente tentando descobrir o que acontece, porém infelizmente sem sucesso.

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Muito obrigado

Comment: HibernateUtil.java como ele está ?

Comment: @LR10, segue acima o HibernateUtil.java.  Muito obrigado

Comment: Você já pensou na possibilidade de usar o Spring para controlar suas transações? Independente disso, já experimentou fechar sua sessionFactory após o commit da transação? Isso pode resolver o problema de too many connections.

Answer (score 0):

**Tenta a sim:**

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: anteriormente eu utilizava desta forma que você sugeriu, porém como minha aplicação faz diversas requisições, uma atrás da outra, ocorriam muitos erros de max_connections devido a sempre ter que abrir e fechar as sessões.  Utilizando o 'getCurrentSession()', este problema reduziu.  Muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Essa aplicação é web ?

Comment: Sim, uma aplicação WEB.